# backbone templates: index.jst.eco to index.jst.ejs

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, erb, ejs, eco

Specific question: this code works in a backbone template index.jst.eco, but it doesn't work in index.jst.ejs

```
<ui>

<% for entry in @entries.models: %>
<li> <%= entry.get('name') %></li>
<% end %>

</ui>
```

I'd like to know why (i.e. how to fix it for ejs), and, more generally, is there comprehensive documentation for how to write code in ejs templates? I can't find anything that goes into detail. As I've been playing around with ejs and eco, I've noticed the presence or absence of a : or a bracket can make a huge impact but I can't figure out how to know what to use and when.

I'm willing to use jst.eco or jst.ejs depending on which syntax has better documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how that eco code would be written in jst.ejs.

```
   <% for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) { %>
    <li> <%= entries.models[i].get('name') %></li>
    <% } %>
```

However, I can't get it to work with a `for entry in entries.models` iterator

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered this problem, here's my solution!

```
<% entries.each(function(entry){%>
  <li><%= entry.get('name') %></li>
<% });%>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've known, jst.eco format is CoffeeScript embedded into jst template, and jst.ejs will only work with JavaScript. That's why in your case it can render this JavaScript iteration:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) { %>
```

but not this CoffeeScript interation:

```
<% for entry in @entries.models: %>
```